# How to split column into multiple columns in Spark 2?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading the data from HDFS into DataFrame using Spark 2.2.0 and Scala 2.11.8:

```
val df = spark.read.text(outputdir)
df.show()
```

I see this result:

```
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|(4056,{community:...|
|(56,{community:56...|
|(2056,{community:...|
+--------------------+
```

If I run `df.head()`, I see more details about the structure of each row:

```
[(4056,{community:1,communitySigmaTot:1020457,internalWeight:0,nodeWeight:1020457})]
```

I want to get the following output:

```
+---------+----------+
|     id  |     value|
+---------+----------+
|4056     |1         |
|56       |56        |
|2056     |20        |
+---------+----------+
```

How can I do it? I tried using `.map(row => row.mkString(","))`, 
but I don't know how to extract the data as I showed.

Comment: Is the input dataset just a text or a more structured format like JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting the data as a single column of strings. The data format is not really specified in the question (ideally it would be something like JSON), but given what we know, we can use a regular expression to extract the number on the left (id) and the community field:

```
val r = """\((\d+),\{.*community:(\d+).*\}\)"""

df.select(
    F.regexp_extract($"value", r, 1).as("id"),
    F.regexp_extract($"value", r, 2).as("community")
).show()
```

Comment: _"The data format is not really specified in the question"_ <-- I can see it just `text` format.

Answer (score 1):

A bunch of regular expressions should give you required result.

```
df.select(
  regexp_extract($"value", "^\\(([0-9]+),.*$", 1) as "id", 
  explode(split(regexp_extract($"value", "^\\(([0-9]+),\\{(.*)\\}\\)$", 2), ",")) as "value"
).withColumn("value", split($"value", ":")(1))
```

Comment: please add more explanation

Answer (score 1):

If your data is always of the following format

```
(4056,{community:1,communitySigmaTot:1020457,internalWeight:0,nodeWeight:1020457})
```

Then you can simply use `split` and `regex_replace` inbuilt functions to get your desired output `dataframe` as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(regexp_replace((split(col("value"), ",")(0)), "\\(", "").as("id"), regexp_replace((split(col("value"), ",")(1)), "\\{community:", "").as("value")  ).show()
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Look, someone downvoted my question without any visible sense;)

Comment: thats what I am surprised too :( there are some stupid people around.